# Ambiguous reference between generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I was trying to create a generic method to read column values from a datarow using the datarowextension methods:

```
public static Nullable<T> SafeRead<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName) where T : struct
    {
        if (row.HasColumn(fieldName))
        {
            return row.Field<Nullable<T>>(fieldName) ?? default(Nullable<T>);
        }
        else
            return default(Nullable<T>);
    }

    public static T SafeRead<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName) where T : class
    {
        if (row.HasColumn(fieldName))
        {
            return row.Field<T>(fieldName) ?? default(T);
        }
        else
            return default(T);
    }
```

When I call this function from my code the compiler complains that there is an ambiguous reference between the two calls which is obvious when I look at the method signatures. However, I am not sure how to handle this without using separate methods.

Comment: How are you even managing to *declare* these two methods? I'd expect the compiler to complain that you're trying to overload just by return value.

Comment: @john you are right about the compiler complaining about ambiguous methods. I was only trying to understand if C# offers a way to specify an overload based on generic parameter constraints.

Comment: Right - that's easy. No, you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value is not part of the identifying method signature. So your methods look like this to the compiler:

```
SafeRead<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName)
```

and

```
SafeRead<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName)
```

-> There is no difference.

you should rename one of the methods.

Comment: I’m not sure that this is technically the relevant point. The relevant point is that the *generic argument* isn’t part of the method signature. The signature, as far as the CLR is concerned, is ``SafeRead`1(…)`` in both cases, regardless of the actual generic argument.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes. You're right, I just wanted to point out that the OP should rename one of his methods.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The generic *constraints* aren't part of the method signature. The *number* of generic type parameters is.

Comment: @Jon Not only the constraint – the *type* of the generic arguments when calling the methods *also* isn’t part of the signature (conceivably it could be, as in C++). But yes, the number is, that’s what I wanted to say.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's not clear what you mean - the *signature* can only include type *parameters*, not arguments. The signature is on the declaration side, not the calling side... I don't really know what you mean by "the type of the generic arguments".

Comment: @Jon In .NET, yes. But in other languages (that’s why I formulated it so generally) type arguments *can* form part of the signature.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the answers. I do understand the problem but I was wondering if there is a better way, than to rename the methods, to devise a single method which can return the value of a column in a datarow and automatically handle the possibility of  the column value to be null. Essentially I was trying to come up with a generic solution taking advantage of the DataRow extension methods to handle DBNull values.

Comment: @snkar you may want to ask a specific question for that.

Comment: @Angelo I guess my original post was actually about this question. I was not trying to understand the reason for the compiler complaining about ambiguous methods. Rather I was trying to figure out a way to achieve the same result without using different method names.

Comment: @snkar well but that was not what you asked. If you ask a new question with the appropriate title and content you most likely will get a better answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: But how can an *argument* (specified as part of a *call*) be part of a *signature* (which is part of the declaration)?

Comment: @Jon *Type argument*. If you call a generic (well, template) function in C++, a new function with a new prototype is instantiated for the call’s type arguments. To be honest, this doesn’t apply at all in C# so I agree that it’s not meaningful to talk about this here …

Comment: @Angelo I did follow your suggestion and added a separate question. Waiting for the responses.

Answer (score -2):

This is because both namespaces contain the same object. To resolve this, use a type alias

*Example*: If `System.Drawing.Image` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls` causing the error then the following `using` statements will allow you to create an alias for the `System.Drawing` classes:

```
using GdiImage = System.Drawing.Image;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```